# How to return to your app using google callback url scheme in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps

I am using the Gooogle Url Scheme to show the directions with the press of a button in swift. How can i use the url callback scheme to get back to my app, after i have opened the native google maps app.
I am using the below code

```
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
                "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(place.latitude),\(place.longitude)&directionsmode=driving")!)

        } else {
            NSLog("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
        }
    }
```

I have tried referring to this link [Google Map Url Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme#add_a_back_button_to_google_maps_for_ios)
if anyone knows how to do it, pls answer with a sample swift code

Comment: Use the google component: https://github.com/googlemaps/OpenInGoogleMaps-iOS

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [OpenInGoogleMaps](https://github.com/googlemaps/OpenInGoogleMaps-iOS) component provided by Google Maps. It even lets you encode a redirect URL to your App, which is displayed on top of the directions in the Google Maps application.

This is what the code looks like in Swift:

```
var place: CLLocationCoordinate2D

var definition = GoogleDirectionsDefinition()
definition.destinationPoint = GoogleDirectionsWaypoint(location: place)
definition.travelMode = GoogleMapsTravelMode.Driving

OpenInGoogleMapsController.sharedInstance().openDirections(definition)
```